# Interaction term renders all terms non-significant

Tags: mixed-model, interaction

In a random effects logistic model, I have two variables of interest:  Call and Visit.  When I run the model, Call and Visit both have a p-value near 0.10.  When I add an interaction term between Call and Visit, all three terms are now much larger than p = 0.10 and don't approach conventional significance.  Why might this be?

Comment: Do you expect the p values to stay the same when new variables enter the model?

Comment: A good question.  I wouldn't expect the p-values to remain the same.  However, if Call and Visit are both independently significant, I wouldn't expect adding a Call * Visit interaction term to render them all insignificant.  At the very least, the interaction term might show significance while the individual terms might fall out of significance.

Answer (score 2):

The individual terms or "main" effects in a model have a completely different interpretation in the presence of an interaction that they do without the interaction. So comparing their p-values with and without the interaction is inappropriate. In the presence of an interaction, the coefficient on one of the predictors is the effect of that predictor on the outcome *when the other predictor is fixed at zero*. Zero may not even be a meaningful value for the other predictor, rendering the coefficient on the main effect nonsensical. This phenomenon is observed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/560085/116195), for example.

Two get an honest p-value for whether the main effect matters in the presence of an interaction, use an ANOVA test. You can also get a more interpretable coefficient by centering both predictors at their means, in which case the main effect of each predictor is the effect of that predictor when the other predictor is fixed at its mean. You can also compute marginal effects to get the average effect of each predictor, collapsing across the other predictor.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the predictors are dummy variables.  I understand how interactions work and how to interpret main effects.  I'm more curious about real world reasons for why two main effects would show significance, but when an interaction term is added, both the main effects AND the interaction term all become non-significant.  It is probably something to do with my data and who is placed in what groups.  I'll probably start there.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The interpretations of the coefficients changes from ones with potentially high precision (the overall effects of the predictors) to one with potentially low precision (the effect of each predictor at the reference level of the other predictor). It also requires a lot of precision to estimate interaction effects, which may be why it is nonsignificant. Without access to the results of your tests or the alternatives I mentioned it is impossible to say what the reason for the phenomenon you observed is.